# How can I structure my architecture server project?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, architecture, webserver

I'm working with Silverlight. In it, I've created a web project.

I always have created desktop application where I divide my projects in three modules:

- Domain
- Application
- Presentation

But now, I'm working to the server side and I really have no much idea about how to build my architecture. In it, I plan to have a entity model for my database.

So, can you give some ideas about the modules how to structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I structure my Silverlight server-side libraries as follows:

- **MyApp.Host**: The main hosting project for the silverlight application. Brings in fact nothing more than the aspx file housing the XAP and the ClientBin folder containing the XAP files. Additionally you can use a global.asax file to run a bootstrapper or any other components needed to startup your server-side application.
- **MyApp.Server.Services**: This project contains all my domain services. The client side libraries have a RIA-Services link set to this project
- **MyApp.Server.Data**: This project contains my Entities, and my data-access-layer, such as database contexts or repositories encapsulating the database access.

Note: This structure is for RIA-Services applications. When using other service types you might want to have a portable library called MyApp.Interfaces for accessing services and entities.